# Cant execute template well in golang

Tags: html, http, templates, go

I'm trying to create some templates and I just can't understand the next thing:
Why doesn't such construction work?
I've got test.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test.html", TestHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func TestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Parsing HTML
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("test.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    Name := "MyName"
    City := "MyCity"
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "T1", Name)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "T2", City)
}
```

And I also have test.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Tamplates</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing some templates</h1>
    <p> Empty template: {{ `"Some text"` }} </p>
    <p> Name is {{ template "T1" . }} </p>
    <p> City is {{ template "T2" . }} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

It's easy example, but somewhy it doesnt work.
I tried adding strings `{{ define "T1" }} {{ . }} {{ end }}` and `{{ define "T2" }} {{ . }} {{ end }}`before h1 header, but it has resulted web page containing just string `MyName MyCity`

Answer (score 4):

**Update (07/02/2016)**

I'm gonna to try to explain as best I can why your code was not been executed properly and a proper solution using **nested templates**.

In your test.html file you were importing two templates: `T1` and `T2`,

```
<p> Name is {{ template "T1" . }} </p>
<p> City is {{ template "T2" . }} </p>
```

those templates should be defined and write in somewhere to be used (a good place to be written could be in separate files). Here is the first issue that I found, this is how you defined them:

```
{{ define "T1" }} {{ . }} {{ end }}
{{ define "T2" }} {{ . }} {{ end }}
```

Note that the `{{.}}` is a shorthand for the current object, so it will render whatever the data you pass when calling the `ExecuteTemplate` function. So, to solve this issue, you should specify which object you want to render in each template:

```
{{ define "T1" }} {{ .Name }} {{ end }}
{{ define "T2" }} {{ .City }} {{ end }}
```

Now, here is the second issue that I found. In your `TestHandler` function, you are just rendering the sub-templates, firstly the `T1` template, and secondly the `T2` template:

```
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "T1", Name)
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "T2", City)
```

so at no time, you are calling to the parent template.

Below you can find how it will look like using nested templates. I hope it will solve your doubt about how to use the templates.

**test.go** file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test.html", TestHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func TestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Parsing HTML
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("test2.html", "t1.tmpl", "t2.tmpl")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    items := struct {
        Name string
        City string
    }{
        Name: "MyName",
        City: "MyCity",
    }
    t.Execute(w, items)
}
```

**test.html** file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Templates</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing some templates</h1>
        <p> Empty template: {{ `"Some text"` }} </p>
        <p> Name is {{ template "T1" . }} </p>
        <p> City is {{ template "T2" . }} </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**t1.tmpl** file

```
{{ define "T1" }} {{ .Name }} {{ end }}
```

**t2.tmpl** file

```
{{ define "T2" }} {{ .City }} {{ end }}
```

---

**Without using sub-templates**:

I did some changes in your code that made it work. I just send the 'Name' and 'City' variable in a struct collection to the [Execute](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) method. Check below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test.html", TestHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func TestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Parsing HTML
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("test.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    items := struct {
        Name string
        City string
    }{
        Name: "MyName",
        City: "MyCity",
    }

    t.Execute(w, items)
}
```

And using `{{.Name}}` and `{{.City}}` to access to those exported fields.

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Tamplates</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing some templates</h1>
        <p> Name is {{.Name}} </p>
        <p> City is {{.City}} </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems easier and really works, thank you.
But is there any way to make stuff like I wished? My goal was to include two different variables. Maybe I've just misunderstood such thing as "define" and "templates"
As I thought, "define" - defines template, "template" executes this. (both are in HTML)
Also, Golang ExecuteTemplate connects template names and variables.
I may be wrong because I could translate documentation not in a right way :)
Thank you

Comment: @utkillr I updated my answer to explain you why your approach was not working properly. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: it looks nice when templated info is quite common (like Name and City can be aggregated in structure called, something like, Info. 
But what to do if I want to template User info (name, city, age for instance) and error info (like when password is wrong so I want to make template for error message)
And both (user info and error message) should be executed to one file.
I don't know, but I guess it's not nice way to create structure like "InfoToShow" containing fields "Error" and "Info"
Or is it proper way to make smth like your item struct?